# How to show first page of pdf with embed tag?

Tags: html, embed

I'm using `<embed>` tag to show pdf on a website but it shows the second page no matter what I do. Suggestions?

My code:

`<embed src="blablabla.pdf#page=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="980px" />`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing the `#page=0` part?

Comment: Yes! Default is `page=1` that shows second page :/